# FLUTTER - How to properly upgrade this code to work with RiverPod 1.0+?

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-hooks

I added the libraries to pubspec.yaml.   In the current project I am not using hooks, but used the package because I want to use this to build a skeleton starter project.

pubspec.yaml:

```
  flutter_hooks: ^0.18.2+1
  hooks_riverpod: ^1.0.3
```

Then I modified the code to the latest RiverPod syntax.  This involved changing things to Consumer widgets and using the ref parameter.  The app now runs but just is not switching from dark mode to light mode and vice versa!

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

class AppThemeState extends StateNotifier<bool> {
  AppThemeState(): super(false);

  void setLightTheme() => state = false;
  void setDarkTheme() => state = true;
}

// Theme
final appThemeStateNotifier = StateNotifierProvider((ref) => AppThemeState());

void main() {
  runApp(ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends HookConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final darkModeEnabled = ref.watch(appThemeStateNotifier);
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: AppTheme.lightTheme,
      darkTheme: AppTheme.darkTheme,
      themeMode: darkModeEnabled != null ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 2.0,
        title: Text("Flutter Theme Riverpod Demo"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text("Light Mode"),
                DarkModeSwitch(),
                Text("Dark Mode"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DarkModeSwitch extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final darkModeEnabled = ref.read(appThemeStateNotifier) == true;

    return //Text('$darkModeEnabled');
    Switch(
      value: darkModeEnabled,
      onChanged: (enabled) {
        if (enabled) {
          ref.read(appThemeStateNotifier.notifier).setDarkTheme();
        } else {
          ref.read(appThemeStateNotifier.notifier).setLightTheme();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class AppTheme {
  // Private Constructor
  AppTheme._();

  static final lightTheme = ThemeData(
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      color: Colors.teal,
      iconTheme: IconThemeData(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    ),
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      bodyText2: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
    ),
  );

  static final darkTheme = ThemeData(
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
      color: Colors.black,
      iconTheme: IconThemeData(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    ),
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      bodyText2: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at this line:

```
themeMode: darkModeEnabled != null ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
```

`darkModeEnabled` can't be null.

Use this instead:

```
themeMode: darkModeEnabled ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light,
```